# What is a "button load cell"?

Tags: load-cell

I just came across this little gadget called "button load cell", it seems to be a sensor that can measure weight but what exactly does it do? What is its intended application? I do not even have an idea about how to install it correctly(nipple facing upwards?).

[This is the one I have by the way.](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=3137) I am not familiar with the terms used in the description page. I have no electrical engineering background and I did not do my physics in English.

Edit: I want to know the mechanics of this gadget(as in how it works). As far as my own study goes, it seems to be measuring the change of shape to derive applied force? But in the description it says `Load cells are designed to measure a specific force, and ignore other forces being applied.` which makes no sense to me.

Also I would like to know the real life application of this gadget. I can imagine using it in a scale but where else can it be useful?

Comment: All the information on what it is? is on the link that you have provided !!

Comment: Weird, I thought I explained why I asked this question by saying "I am not familiar with the terms used in the description page. I have no electrical engineering background and I did not do my physics in English." which means I do not understand the information they provide. Being able to read the words does not necessarily mean being able to understand what the words mean. At least 5 people do not have this logic circuit in their brain.@Arjun

Comment: @anetworknoobie Then you should be more specific about what terms on that page you don't understand. How are we to describe what it is if we don't know what terminology is off limits? Insulting people trying to help you is a good way to deter them, too.

Comment: @NickJohnson Right, I should have been more specific, my mistake. Question has been updated. But I do not think "stating the fact" = "insulting", and those people probably did not want to help anyway(as they did not leave a comment saying I should be more specific etc etc). If you think "duh stupid question, down vote!" and leave; or up voting a comment that contains no helpful information to me at all = trying to help, then that is your call...I will not judge.

Comment: I don't think "At least 5 people do not have this logic circuit in their brain" is any sort of fact you're stating.

Comment: Insulting people who come looking for help also isn't exactly the point this platform was created for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First to begin with - that's a force sensor, which is designed to (just like you suspected) measure weight. It's intended application is wiring it to amplifying circuit, and your measuring device. You apply force to the button (or nipple, as you named it) and calculate the result basing on a formula, you can find in the datasheet for your load cell. From what I've seen, the one you have is using this one:
Measured Value[kg] = 25 * Measured mV/V + Offset
Where offset value is calculated by measuring output of the cell sensor with no load applied to it, and using this formula:
Offset = 0 - 46.335 * Measured Output

You have to remember that you need to amplify the output of the sensor, page you linked hints to http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=1046 which takes care of amplifying and measurement.

You can read more [here](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/Load_Cell_Primer)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have some examples of where this thing can be used? I can only think of using it as a scale(with a plate atop)

Comment: Not only scale reacts to shifts in force applied - you could use it as an alarm trigger (e. g. someone stepping on it causes alarm to go off), or even for some emergency procedures like air-bag system. You just need to find a way where shift of weight/force should be a signal for your device